# How to have a textfile automatically delete after a certain time period using a timer

Tags: vb.net

I am doing a project using text files to do order and view restaurant orders. I am looking to use a timer to automatically delete a text file which holds order details after an hour. The rest of my code works it's just the automatic timer does not work.

```
Public Class frmOrderSummary
Dim strOrderName As String = ""
Private Sub frmSummary_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'calling display order sub
    Call DisplayOrder()
    timerOrder.Start()
    Dim FileToDelete As String
    timerOrder.Start()
    FileToDelete = (txtOrderNum.Text & ".txt")
    If System.IO.File.Exists(FileToDelete) = True And timerOrder.Interval = 400 Then
        System.IO.File.Delete(FileToDelete)
        MessageBox.Show("File Deleted")
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub lstOrders_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstOrders.SelectedIndexChanged
    'items selected from listbox will appear in textbox below
    strOrderName = lstOrders.Text
    txtOrderNum.Text = lstOrders.Text

End Sub
Sub DisplayOrder()
    'adding items from OrderNums.txt to listbox
    lstOrders.Items.Clear()
    If IO.File.Exists("OrderNums.txt") Then
        Dim query = From OrderNum In IO.File.ReadAllLines("OrderNums.txt")
                    Order By OrderNum Ascending
                    Select OrderNum
        For Each OrderNum In query
            lstOrders.Items.Add(OrderNum)

        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    'using textfile to assign stored data to specific textboxes using arrays
    If (txtOrderNum.Text & ".txt" <> "") And IO.File.Exists(txtOrderNum.Text & ".txt") Then
        Dim query = From line In IO.File.ReadAllLines(txtOrderNum.Text & ".txt")

        Dim name = query(0).Split(","c)(0)
        Dim surname = query(0).Split(",")(1)
        Dim address = query(0).Split(","c)(2)
        Dim phonenum = query(0).Split(","c)(3)
        Dim method = query(0).Split(","c)(4)

        txtName.Text = name
        txtSurname.Text = surname
        txtAddress.Text = address
        txtPhoneNum.Text = phonenum
        txtMethod.Text = method

        Dim cellvalue(20) As String
        Dim OrderID As String
        OrderID = txtOrderNum.Text

        Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(OrderID & ".txt")
        For index = 1 To lines.Length - 1
            Dim cells = lines(index).Split(","c)
            dgvOutput.Rows.Add(cells)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the code for the timer (elapsed) that you say is not working?

Comment: instetad of your current code, create a timer control. and set the interval for that. move the file deletion code into that timer's tick event and also add a line to disable the timer